# Is it safe to delete the older setup files of the Ext Pack of a VB after installing a new version of Ext Pack?

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox

My PC runs on Ubuntu 14.04 and hosts an Oracle VB. Since installing the VB I have twice received notifications asking me to  download and install a newer version of Extension Pack, and I have done so. But as a result, I now have two redundant setup files of older versions of the Extension Pack. Can anyone having the relevant experience please tell me whether it is safe to simply delete these redundant files? Or should I,before installing the new Ext Pack, first uninstall the earlier one and, in that case,  what is the way to do it?

(The notification from Oracle asked me to upgrade, and I suppose upgrading would have automatically taken care of all this. But for some reason, the "Upgrade" option is not working and I have to manually install the new Ext Pack from the freshly downloaded setup file. Hence my problem.)

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly safe to delete the old versions of the files once the new version has been installed. The only exception would be if you wanted to roll back to an older version of VirtualBox, though that would entail installing it outside of the normal `apt` framework, so is quite unusual. Also all of the previous extension packs are still available on the [Oracle download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3).

I normally install the new extension pack using the `--replace` option to uninstall the old extension pack at the same time, like so (replace the extension pack name with the correct one):

```
vboxmanage extpack install --replace /path/to/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.36-105129.vbox-extpack
```

I also make sure that this is the extpack used by virtualbox for VRDP connections with:

```
vboxmanage setproperty vrdeextpack "Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack"
```

Though this final step may be unnecessary if completed for a previous extension pack.

Comment: @Arronical.--Sorry, being a novice I have to ask again. Where exactly are the names of the new and old ext packs  to be inserted in the terminal command? Does the NEW name go between "install" and "replace", where the dotted line is? And is the name that appears ("...4.3.36-105129") an example of the OLD one to be replaced? Lastly, does this single command both download and install?

Comment: No problem, you don't need to mention the old ext pack in the command, it's actually two hyphens before the word `replace`, which means you're using the replace option of the `vboxmanage extpack install` command, this will just replace whatever is already installed. You need to download the new ext pack separately, and have it somewhere on the host system, which is why I included the `/path/to` bit in the command. You need to tell the virtualbox command exactly where the file is on your system.

Comment: The name of the new ext pack is the whole `Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.36-105129.vbox-extpack` part. Hope that's clear, comment again if not :)

Comment: No, sorry, can't manage it. I typed in the name of my new extpack all right, but Terminal sent back the error message that the file couldn't be located and  that the "Usual usage" is: "VBoxManage extpack install [--replace] <tarball>" -- which I don't understand. I also suspect I couldn't rightly specify the location. In my Windows days my HDD had several partitions, which I retained when switching to Ubuntu. The downloaded extpack file is in Local Disk G.  Maybe it would be easier to double-click the file, install it and delete the earlier downloads (provided it's safe, that is)?

Comment: Having different partitions shouldn't stop your file from being located, but if you're not sure of the filepath, that'll cause the problem. It's probably in `/home/username/Downloads`, where `username` corresponds to your actual username. If you can install it by double clicking in the GUI, that may be the way to go. If the newer version installs correctly, it should definitely be safe to delete the previous versions. You can check which version you have installed with the terminal command: `vboxmanage list extpacks` the output will have a field called Version containing the number.

Comment: No, I downloaded the file in the partition "Local Disk G" and it is there. My problem is how to describe this location and where exactly to insert it in the Terminal command suggested by you. Should it REPLACE any word or words (such as "path/to/...") or should it be ADDED at a particular point? Double-clicking remains the last resort but I'd also like to learn the Terminal way, if possible.

Comment: If you type the following command, it should tell you exactly where your ext pack is located: `find / -type f -iname *Oracle_VM*`. You may need to write `sudo` at the beginning of that command. Let me know what the outcome is.

Comment: I didn't have to write "sudo". The outcome is dozens of "Permission denied" messages and then: "VBoxManage error: Too many extension pack names given to "extpack uninstall"

Usage:
  VBoxManage extpack install [--replace] <tarball>"

Comment: Ah, I meant for you to type the `find` command as a completely separate thing to the `vboxmanage` one. The 'Permission denied' messages are because find is searching locations in which you don't have permission to look, which is why you'd need to use sudo. What happens if you drag the file from your file browser into a terminal window?

Comment: I did use the find command separately. Anyhow, just now I've found that adding sudo does it. So I've copied the info that's come up and pasted it after "-- replace" in your terminal command. At first it seems to work (asks for my password) but then comes up with the same error message as before.... In the mean time can you tell me where can one find all these Terminal commands for different purposes?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide are good places to start. Though the VirtualBox commands won't be there, you can find those here http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp55423424 . Note that there should be no spaces between the hyphens and word in `--replace`. Also `find` will be giving you the path for every ext pack on your system, you should only put the most recent into the `vboxmanage` command, you should also put a double quote `"` at the beginning and the end of that path, because there are spaces in that path.

Comment: I won't be available over the weekend, can pick this up later, perhaps in chat. Either way I will clean up comments then.